# Error in VBA: Choosing discontinuous cell ranges in the loop

Tags: excel, vba

My requirement is to change the cell background color for different cells in a row, based on the text input in the cell of column C. This applies for all the rows in the sheet.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long

For i = 4 To 1800
Range("D" & i, "AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0


If Range("C" & i) = "Open" Then
    Range("F" & i & ":H" & i, "K" & i, "L" & i, "AA"&i, "AD"&i, "AF"&i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ElseIf Range("C" & i) = "Boil" Then
    Range("I" & i, "S" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

but this is giving error, saying" wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Let me know, where i went wrong. I'm new to VBA and this is very frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer not concatenating too many things together and to use a token replacement approach instead:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    
    Me.Range("D4", "AW1800").Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'faster like this...
    For i = 4 To 1800
        Select Case Me.Range("C" & i).Value
            Case "Open"
                Me.Range(Replace("F?:H?,K?,L?,AA?,AD?,AF?", "?", i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            Case "Boil"
                Me.Range("I" & i, "S" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `v` a typo? Doesn't look like it's been used anywhere. I like the token replacement approach, learnt something new!

Comment: Love the token replacement, I'll be using that! +1

Comment: Always a joy to see such neat solutions.

Comment: @xaea12 If this answers your question then please accept it by clicking the tick beside it.

Comment: Seeing this replace function usage I feel like Neo hearing about Matrix. Wow! +1

Comment: @RaymondWu - yes an orphaned variable; removed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you (really) need to process all the range in case of any change, please use the next way. It should be very fast, putting all cases in Union ranges and format them at the end, at once:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, rngD As Range, rngO As Range, rngB As Range
    
    For i = 4 To 1800
        If rngD Is Nothing Then
            Set rngD = Range("D" & i, "AW" & i)
        Else
            Set rngD = Union(rngD, Range("D" & i, "AW" & i))
        End If
        Select Case Range("C" & i)
            Case "Open"
                If rngO Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngO = Range("F" & i & ":H" & i & ",K" & i & ",L" & i & ",AA" & i & ",AD" & i & ",AF" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngO = Union(rngO, Range("F" & i & ":H" & i & ",K" & i & ",L" & i & ",AA" & i & ",AD" & i & ",AF" & i))
                End If
            Case "Boil"
                If rngB Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngB = Range("I" & i, "S" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngB = Union(rngB, Range("I" & i, "S" & i))
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
     If Not rngD Is Nothing Then rngD.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
     If Not rngO Is Nothing Then rngO.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
     If Not rngO Is Nothing Then rngO.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End Sub
```

But, being such an event, the above code should be placed in a standard module and **run only once** and the event should deal **only with the changed cell**. `Target` I mean...

Then do you really need to trigger this processing for any change **in all the sheet**. If not, like I suppose, the code should limit the range where a changed to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

In Range only two arguments are allowed.
Also there is no need to update to whole document. The target value specify the values which have changed, so looping trough all the cells, which have changed it much faster. Only if the column of the changed cell is in three (column C has the formation command), the code has to run.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Target
    If rng.Column = 3 Then
        i = rng.Row
        
        Range("D" & i, "AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        
        If Range("C" & i) = "Open" Then
             Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
             Range("K" & i, "L" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
             Range("AA" & i, "AD" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
             Range("AF" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
             
        ElseIf Range("C" & i) = "Boil" Then
            Range("I" & i, "S" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            
        End If

    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to too many arguments provided to `Range` in the "Open" scenario.

It's not exactly clear which column you want to change the `ColorIndex` so below code will do the following:

- "Open" - Change column F to H, K, L, AA, AD and AF.
- "Boil" - Change column I to S.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 4 To 1800
        Range("D" & i, "AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        
        Select Case Range("C" & i)
            Case "Open"
                Range("F" & i & ":H" & i & ",K" & i & ",L" & i & ",AA" & i & ",AD" & i & ",AF" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            Case "Boil"
                Range("I" & i, "S" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```